# How do you make a systemd service for autostarting RemoteLauncher at boot?

Tags: java, launcher, systemd, autostart, kodi

I want RemoteLauncher to autostart at boot so I can do things like start/stop/control Kodi on 18.10.

RemoteLauncher is [here](http://owtroid.com/remotelauncher/mediawiki/index.php?title=Remote_Launcher).

An old method to autostart it is [here](http://blog.copywaste.org/index.php/2011/10/08/recording-audio-on-ubuntu-while-watching-tv-with-my-android-phone/#comment-10406). (I believe this method has been replaced by Systemd.)

I've tried doing something like [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux).

The old method does start the java and the service. I can see them running in the System Monitor. But the launcher to start Kodi doesn't start Kodi on the screen. I see Kodi running for less than a minute in the System Monitor, then it disappears.

Starting the service manually in a terminal with `/usr/bin/remote-launcher-server` does start java and the service, and allows the launcher to start Kodi properly so I can see it on-screen. Another launcher can kill it. But the goal is to have this capability working automatically after booting.

I cannot get the last Systemd method to even get java and the service running after boot. I am at a dead-end, and am not savvy enough with Ubuntu or Systemd to figure it out. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

What worked was just adding `/usr/bin/remote-launcher-server` as a Startup Application. (I don't know why I was making it so hard.)

Comment: This will run the application when you _log in_, not when the machine _boots_.